# Finding thevenin voltage

Tags: thevenin

When finding Thevenin voltage am I able to simplify the circuit to make it easier? For example if there were resistors in a series am I able to combine them to reduce the amount of nodes I am dealing with?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for resistors in series -- as long as the node you are trying to find the Thevenin equivalent of is not one of the nodes that gets eliminated.

You can also simplify for resistors in parallel.

Ultimately you are trying to solve the circuit for a given condition (typically open and shorted at the terminals). Any analysis technique that correctly preserves that result is valid. Parallel or series resistors is a useful by-observation simplification.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification